# How to set value for Field at state parent from child component

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 Components: Community.js and Edit.js

I call to Edit from Community below:

```html
<DetailModal
                    DetailModal={Detail}
                    errors={this.state.errors}
                    uploadFile={this.props.uploadFileActions.uploadFile}
                    onSave={this.save}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    mode={this.state.mode}
                    data={this.state.details}
                    isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                    closeModal={this.closeModal}
                    editable={isHasEditPermisson}
                />
```

At Community, I have a function onchange() below:

```html
onChange = (field, data) => {
        let value = null;
        if (data) {
            value = data
        }
        this.setState(state => ({
            details: {
                ...state.details,
                [field]: value
            },
            errors: {
                ...state.errors,
                [field]: undefined
            }
        }));
        // }
    }
```

At Edit, I have a function which called to select image/video file:

```html
selectFile = (file) => {
        if (file && file.target.files.length > 0) {
            const checkType = file.target.files[0].type.split('/')[0]
            const extendType = file.target.files[0].type.split('/')[1]
            const fileArr = [];
            // if (checkType === "video") {
            //     console.log('this.getDuration(file)', this.getDuration(file))
            //     if (this.getDuration(file) > 60) {
            //         alert("stop");
            //         return;
            //     }
            // }
            // this.props.uploadFile(file.target.files[0], (res) => {
            //     this.props.onChange('ResourceUrl', `${this.props.data.ResourceUrl ? `${this.props.data.ResourceUrl};` : ''}${res.data.Data}`);
            // });
            fileArr.push({
                file: file.target.files[0],
                urlFile: URL.createObjectURL(file.target.files[0]),
            });
            this.props.onChange('ResourceUrl', `${this.props.data.ResourceUrl ? `${this.props.data.ResourceUrl};` : ''}${fileArr[0].urlFile}`);
            this.props.onChange('ResourceFile', this.props.data.ResourceFile ? this.props.data.ResourceFile : fileArr[0].file);
            if (checkType === "image") {
                this.setState({
                    fileType: "image/*",
                    extend: extendType
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    fileType: "video/*",
                    countVideo: 1,
                    extend: extendType
                })
            }
            // file.target.value = '';
        }
    }
```

This is Init state in Community:

```html
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.escFunction = this.escFunction.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            modalIsOpen: false,
            mode: 'add',
            details: {},
            errors: {},
            defaultRole: constants.CollaboratorRole.default,
            permanentRole: constants.CollaboratorRole.permanent,
            isOpenDeleteConfirm: false
        };
    }
```

Here, I call to onchange() in Community to set value for 2 field: ResourceUrl, ResourceFile

But I have an issue when set value for ResourceFile. When I choose second file then I still get value of first file.
I don't know how to set the value of the second file into ResourceFile, which means that I expect that ResourceFile is an array containing the information of the two files I just selected.

Comment: Can you share the initial state value in `Community`?

Comment: I have just updated, thank you